# Unexpected double data type when division of two integer in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R and try to find out simple operations.
When I run the code below, I get the double results even though I divide the two integer variables.

```
p <- 10L
l <- 2L
t <- (p / l)
typeof(t)
```

Output: [1] "double"

What is the reason of this? Is it necessary to implement any other thing to get integer value?

Comment: `R` likes to be "helpful" by doing things like format conversions without being asked.  Sometimes it is nice and saves you a lot of coding.  Other times it makes you pull out your hair out because `colSums(myMatrix[,mycols])` throws an error after you have been using it for months because this time `mycols` is length 1 and `R` decided to "help" by turning your matrix into a vector for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer division in R is done with `%/%`

```
(p %/% l)
# [1] 5
typeof(p %/% l)
# [1] "integer"
```

See the `?Arithmetic` help page.